# Answering a not-quite-duplicate

Tags: discussion

I haven't created a duplicate question... and I don't even want it to be necessarily reopened. I'd just like to be able to post an answer (either to it, or to the supposed "original" question)

Obviously, as it almost always happens... duplicates aren't perfect duplicates, and in this case there's a rule in the new question (that I'd obviously exploit) that'd disqualify my code in the original one.

How should I do it? I'd prefer to have to avoid defending myself (and inevitably receiving downvotes) on the "original" question, due to not exactly following its rules (after all, I'm already pre-emptively kind-of defending myself here)

At the same time, due to the (imo unreasonable) reputation requirements, I cannot even cast a single re-open vote, so that wouldn't work as well.

Recreating a question by explicitly specifying the caveat that imho differentiates the queston is very likely to -at best- get the new question closed (a waste of time without any useful outcome) and -at worst- to actually receive some downvotes.

Should I just give up?

Thanks

PS: here's the link to the latest such question I found: [Python - Reverse Polish Notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/python-reverse-polish-notation?rq=1)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the specific question you're referring to?

Comment: Loopholes seemed not being well received here anymore. But if you mean `eval`, you can try [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5847/25180).